# Case for "The upcoming summer"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

What should be the case for "the upcoming summer" as in the following sentences?

> Der kommende Sommer werde ich wahrscheinlich nach Deutschland gehen.

or

> Den kommenden Sommer werde ich wahrscheinlich nach Deutschland gehen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accusative as in your second sentence is correct:

> Den kommenden Sommer werde ich wahrscheinlich nach Deutschland gehen.

The direct article can be left without change of meaning:

> Kommenden Sommer werde ich wahrscheinlich nach Deutschland gehen.

Answer (score 2):

Time complements without preposition stay in acusative. For instance, what Toscho stated in his answer. But also

> - Nächste Woche werde ich nicht arbeten, weil ich noch sehr krank bin.
> - Nächstes Jahr reise ich nach Schweden.
> - Nur einen Tag war ich in Österreich.